# Accelerometer not returning 0 values when the iphone is not moving

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a simple app that just implements the accelerometer stuff and the NSLogs the results to the console.

```
2011-03-11 00:35:38.248 Accel[1070:307] ************
2011-03-11 00:35:38.737 Accel[1070:307] x: -0.0362244
2011-03-11 00:35:38.743 Accel[1070:307] y: -0.0181122
2011-03-11 00:35:38.747 Accel[1070:307] z: -1.03239
2011-03-11 00:35:38.750 Accel[1070:307] ************
2011-03-11 00:35:39.238 Accel[1070:307] x: -0.0181122
2011-03-11 00:35:39.243 Accel[1070:307] y: -0.0181122
2011-03-11 00:35:39.248 Accel[1070:307] z: -1.03239
2011-03-11 00:35:39.250 Accel[1070:307] ************
2011-03-11 00:35:39.739 Accel[1070:307] x: -0.0181122
2011-03-11 00:35:39.744 Accel[1070:307] y: -0.0181122
2011-03-11 00:35:39.749 Accel[1070:307] z: -1.03239
2011-03-11 00:35:39.751 Accel[1070:307] ************
2011-03-11 00:35:40.240 Accel[1070:307] x: -0.0362244
2011-03-11 00:35:40.245 Accel[1070:307] y: -0.0362244
2011-03-11 00:35:40.249 Accel[1070:307] z: -1.05051
2011-03-11 00:35:40.252 Accel[1070:307] ************
2011-03-11 00:35:40.741 Accel[1070:307] x: -0.0362244
2011-03-11 00:35:40.746 Accel[1070:307] y: -0.0362244
2011-03-11 00:35:40.750 Accel[1070:307] z: -1.05051
2011-03-11 00:35:40.752 Accel[1070:307] ************
2011-03-11 00:35:41.241 Accel[1070:307] x: -0.0362244
2011-03-11 00:35:41.247 Accel[1070:307] y: -0.0181122
2011-03-11 00:35:41.251 Accel[1070:307] z: -1.03239
2011-03-11 00:35:41.253 Accel[1070:307] ************
```

I would have expected 0 for x,y & z, as the phone is resting on the table and not being moved.

So from research i find that accelerometers always read the a resting phone always read that the +1g on the z-axis unless the phone is in free fall.
So that explains some of the z-axis reading.

But the .03 to .01 extra on the x,y,z(after adjusting the z-axis for the +1g) is some kind of margin for error ?

Should i be doing something to all these values to get a more true reading?

As i would like to graph the results.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just means that your table isn't perfectly level and gravity is above average in your area. There is probably a little error, but it should be accurate to a few decimal places at least.

Comment: "table isn't perfectly level" so its not reading the movement? Its reading the pull of gravity to the side of the accelerometer?

Comment: @Code You said it was sitting still. If it isn't moving, then the only acceleration is caused by gravity (actually, the table counteracting gravity, but the difference isn't really important).

Answer (score 1):

When using accelerometer values for any kind of practical uses, use a high pass filter on the values. You can also normalise the gravity vector returned by the accelerometer to get a normal gravity vector.

Comment: Use a filter to remove some of the accuracy of the values? To cancel out the .03(margin for error) of the readings?

Comment: the filter will stabilize your values so they dont jump to extremes really fast. when using accelerometer values without the filter, for instance in a game, the results can be jittery. but i guess it depends what usage you have of the accelerometer values.